# Minimum accuracy of startMonitoringForRegion in meters

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I've encountered problem with startMonitoringForRegion method in iOS 5. Documentation says that method is taking parameter "accuracy":

```
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region desiredAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)accuracy
```

I'm currently developing an app that should notify user when he's in 25 meters radius from monitored point. App uses GPS with kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation setting. I'm creating (CLRegion *)region like this:

```
CLRegion *pointRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:pointLocation radius:25.0 identifier:identifier];
```

and setting accuracy parameter in startMonitoringForRegion for kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation.

Region monitoring works well in my app, however didEnterRegion method fires when user is around 100 meters from monitored region, not 25 meters.

Is there minimum value of radius in startMonitoringForRegion that is not described in Apple's documentation or am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to set region monitoring to relatively small values (like 5-25 meters)?

Comment: Are you talking about background location notifications? This might be useful:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set iOS Region Monitoring to lower values unless turning on significantLocationChanges. It's only working in US in bigger cities because region monitoring is based on cellular network.

Comment: It seems you are correct. If we want to have better accuracy we need to write our own implementation, one way is using distance parameter from point to point. Thanks.

Comment: Region monitoring in iOs 5 and higher is also based on wifi signals.